# play the sound from mic using the AUGraph

Tags: iphone, audio, media, core-audio, audiounit

when i'am using the AUGraph to realize playing sound from the mic,

i have a problem, in the device(iphone 3g), i can only hear from the right side of the headset,

but it is well in the simulator, i can hear from both of the side of the headset.

here are the code i use to connect the input to the output:

AUGraphConnectNodeInput(auGraph, remoteIONode, 1, remoteIONode, 0);

someone help me?

tks!

Comment: What does the kAudioOutputUnitProperty_ChannelMap look like for your graph's output AU?

Answer (score 2):

output is double channel, input is also double channel. i find that the data from mic is single channel when it is in a device, but the data is double channel when it is in a simulation.i am puzzle! so i change the single channel data to the double channel data, the problem is solved! oh, my lady gaga, my english is so poor!